# Helm create template for template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to create a helm template for a template file inside `templates/` folder? My use case is following: there are several kubernetes deployment files which differs only in deployment name and docker image that is pulled from a repo(e.g. deployment for `service1`, `service2` etc). I want to create one chart to deploy all that services. Currently there are a lot of copy-paste in my deployment templates. I want to have some kind of a template for that templates. Also all that deployment templates will have different `Values.yaml` on different environments(e.g. service1 and service2 will have `values-prod.yaml` on prod env and `values-stage.yaml` on staging env)

If not possible, what are the alternative solutions? Thanks

Comment: You can use the `{{ templating syntax }}` in any file in the `templates/` directory, and do almost arbitrarily complex things using it.  Is there a specific setup you're having trouble with?

Comment: @DavidMaze Doesn't it contradict with the fact that helm requires one resource definition per template file?(I assumed you proposed me to use `{{ range something}}` and then iterate over reource definitions, right?)

Comment: There's no such rule; a template file can create zero resources, or many (make sure to put the YAML `---` document separator before each, possibly inside your `range` statement).

Comment: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/templates/#structure-of-templates there is a mention that `Each resource definition should be in its own template file`

Comment: That's true for typical application charts, but it's not a hard requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are interseted in a solution:
as proposed by David Maze in the comments to my question I should use somehing similar to `{{ range .Values.resourceNames }}` in the template file(e.g. `deployment.yaml`) and divide those resources with `---` on the beginning of a loop(kubernetes allows to have several resources defined in a single file separated by `---`), where `.Values.resourceNames` is just an example. So having that `deployment.yaml` template could look like following:

```
{{- range .Values.resourceNames }}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}-deployment
  labels:
    app: {{ .name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .replicaCount }}
  selector:
    ...
{{- end }}
```

where `values.yaml` file looks like folloiwng:

```
resourceNames:
  - name: service1
    replicaCount: 2
  - name: service2
    replicaCount: 1
```